# Machine Learning issue with Categorical Variables get_dummies()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I hope that someone will be able to help.

I have a dataframe that looks like:

Country  Category  Duration  Succeed

X = [Country, Category, Duration] 
y= [Succeed]

I have 3 countries (GERMANY, FRANCE, ITALY in my training set

after converting the categorical variables to dummies using :

```
 X = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=['COUNTRY','CATEGORY'])
```

I have the X dataframe that looks like:

Country_GERMANY  Country_FRANCE  Country_ITALY  Category  Duration
...

after training, I save the model using

```
joblib.dump(classifier,'csv_final_results/model_classification_joblib')
```

Next when I retrieve my model (with joblib.load) and run it on a set that has multiple rows but one country ITALY, (after running the get_dummies...)

I have the new X that looks like:

Country_ITALY  Category  Duration
...

when predicting y_predict = loadedmodel.predict(X), I have an error saying that the training set size was different.

My question is, are we obliged to always provide a set to predict with the same number of variations for the categorical variables that were in the training set?

Like here, 3 for Country in the training set and 1 in the new set to predict.

What should I do to avoid such a trap?

I hope this was clear.

Thank you and stay safe

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946006/one-hot-encoding-train-with-values-not-present-on-test/57946273#57946273

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One hot encoding train with values not present on test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946006/one-hot-encoding-train-with-values-not-present-on-test)

Comment: Thank you. The pb remains the same with OneHotEncoder when training set columns differ from test set because of values in categorical elements