# Python Linear Regression TypeError: float() argument must be a string or number, not 'method'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've just started trying machine learning, and I'm trying to make a model that can predict if a inputted phrase is considered suicidal or not. This is the code I've gotten so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

data = pd.read_csv("Train.csv")
data.head()
data = data[["PHRASE", 'SUICIDAL']]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

train_x = np.array(data["PHRASE"])
train_y = np.array(data["SUICIDAL"])


regr.fit(train_x, train_y)
train_x, train_y = regr.transform()
```

And this is the error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'

Any idea what's up?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what line is throwing the error. The line `from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression` is unnessecary since you already imported the whole `linear_model` module. It's possible that the error is coming from having linear regression imported twice as `LinearRegression` and as `sklearn.LinearRegression`.

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback log? Besides, it'd be great if you provide a data sample from your csv file (if it's not confidential)

Comment: @Jacob I've removed the 2nd import, but that didn't work. The line causing the error is 
`regr.fit(train_x, train_y)`.

Comment: @Cypherius here's the traceback log: [https://imgur.com/a/KJr1XeU]. I'll see if I'm allowed to get the data sample in a bit.

Comment: What is the input here? It could be that `train_y` is not numeric.

Comment: @Shaido train_y the x and y values are strings. How would I make them numeric?

Comment: Also rerunning the code now says that the values of data["PHRASE"]  cannot be converted to a float. How would I get around this?

Comment: You need to use numeric data, strings won't work. See if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007308/linear-regression-analysis-with-string-categorical-features-variables